# mongodb persistence patterns for JSON client app, jackson mapper or morphia driver?

Tags: mongodb, jackson, morphia

I've started a new job where they are using **mongodb in a java environment**.

They have implemented a pattern using DTOs and factories with the morphia driver, this may be due to a migration onto mongodb from a key value store previously. The client is a **JSON client**.

It seems to me that the [jackson-mongo-mapper](http://vznet.github.com/mongo-jackson-mapper/) would be a better approach because it's just mapping pojos from json to BSON and back, seems like it could **do away with all DTO factory facade?**

Anyone know any pros and cons with these different approaches?

Comment: DTOs will help if you migrate to other database. All you need to write is DTOs for the new database.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data for Mongodb is very nice since you can use even another data store or mix them and repository interface is very helpful.

Kundera is an option through JPA2
http://agilemobiledeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/working-with-mongodb-using-kundera/

There's a lot of java to mongodb options.

http://www.agilemobiledeveloper.com/2013/01/31/hibernate-ogm-mongodb-vs-kundera-vs-jongo-vs-mongodb-api-vs-morphia-vs-spring-data-mongo-mongodb-drivers-for-java/

Adding your own data layer and making sure you use DI and test it fully is very helpful.

NOSQLUnit is awesome ->  https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit

Comment: We have also used Spring Data for this purpose and very happy with that. I believe libraries like Playorm would also be able to do the justice.

Answer (score 0):

DTOs are good for keeping a separation between implementation and design, so when they need or want to switch from mongo to some other NoSQL or SQL database it can be done cleanly.